# NoneType error while region of interest

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, nonetype

```
for i in range(0,3):  
        for j in range(0,3):  
            im=img[100*i:(100*i)+100,100*j:(100*j)+100]  
            shape= shapedetect(im)  
            clr= colordetect(im)  
            size_s= size(im)  
            list.append(shape)  
            list_clr.append(clr)  
            list_siz.append(size_s)  
            list_contnr.append(check_cnb(shape,clr,size_s))
```

This is part of my program in opencv python. I have taken the region of interest
of and image which is already declared earlier i.e. `img=cv2.imread('board_8.jpg')`
but while running the code it gives me an error `NoneType has no attribute '_getitem_'` on the line:

```
im=img[100*i:(100*i)+100,100*j:(100*j)+100]
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if the image `img` has not been properly read in. Most likely this is due to the fact that the path to the image is wrong and there is no file named *'board_8.jpg'* in the current working directory.